# Dropdown menu with html css javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

If somebody can help with this?
What's wrong with the code :/
I'm trying to make a dropdown menu and I have problems with javascript code.

Getting this error:
main.js: 9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')
at HTMLAnchorElement. (main.js:9)

Its says that the problem is with adding the add class on sidebarUl.classList.add('show');

```js
const sidebarBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar-btn');
    const sidebarUl = document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar-ul');
    
    sidebarBtn.forEach((btn) =>
      btn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        const clicked = e.target;
        console.log(clicked);
        if (clicked) {
          sidebarUl.classList.add('show');
        } else {
          sidebarUl.classList.remove('show');
        }
      })
    );
```

```css
.shop-sidenav {
      position: fixed;
      width: 20%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .sidebar ul {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .sidebar ul li {
      line-height: 60px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid var(--primary-color);
    }
    .sidebar ul li a {
      padding-left: 2rem;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      border-left: 1 px solid var(--primary-color);
    }
    .sidebar ul li a:hover {
      color: var(--secondery-color);
    }
    
    .sidebar ul li a span {
      float: right;
      color: var(--secondery-color);
      transition: transform 0.3s;
    }
    .sidebar ul li a:active span {
      transform: rotate(-180deg);
    }
    .sidebar ul ul {
      position: static;
      display: none;
    }
    .sidebar-ul.show {
      display: block;
    }
    .sidebar ul ul li {
      border-bottom: none;
      line-height: 40px;
    }
    .sidebar ul ul li a {
      color: var(--secondery-color);
      padding-left: 4rem;
    }
```

```html
 

    <nav class="sidebar">
          <div class="shop-sidenav">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="sidebar-btn">Bikes<span>&#11167;</span></a>
                <ul class="sidebar-ul">
                  <li><a href="#">Giant</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Piaggio</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Trek</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Scoot</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Canyon</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Cube</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="sidebar-btn">Clothing <span>&#11167;</span></a>
                <ul class="sidebar-ul">
                  <li><a href="#">Enduro</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Scoot</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Fox</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="sidebar-btn">Components<span>&#11167;</span></a>
                <ul class="sidebar-ul">
                  <li><a href="#">Wheels</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Chain</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Gears</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Brakes</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Pumps</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Amortizers</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll` returns a list of nodes. So when adding class `show` to sidebarUl you need to specify to which element you need to add. `forEach` loop gives you an index with that you can acheive that

```
  const sidebarBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".sidebar-btn");
  const sidebarUl = document.querySelectorAll(".sidebar-ul");

  sidebarBtn.forEach((btn,index) =>
    btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        sidebarUl.forEach(ul=>{
            ul.classList.remove("show")
        })
        sidebarUl[index].classList.add("show");
    })
  );
```